# Providing additional parameters to the VM being provisioned on Azure

Tags: linux, azure, puppet, provisioning, azure-virtual-machine

I'm creating Azure VM's through the portal and the API, everything ok with that. But what I'm now looking for is how I can add additional parameters / arguments to the OS which is being provisioned. I have looked into the Azure Agent (Linux Waagent for example), but this agent seems limited to the network config like DNS and resolv.

I would like to use these parameters to configure Puppet and some custom facts (just a file).

Any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: You're welcome. In the future, you should comment on the answer, rather than the question (so that people know what your comment is related to, should there be additional posted answers in the future). And... upvotes and accepted answers are far more effective (and more in line with the StackOverflow model) than 'thank you' comments.

Comment: This may be of interest for you: [Windows Azure Provisioning of Linux and Windows via Puppet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2013/12/12/windows-azure-provisioning-of-linux-and-windows-via-puppet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [REST API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157194.aspx)  for creating a Virtual Machine deployment, specifically the `<CustomData>` element. This lets you inject up to 64K of binary data to your VM, which results in a `CustomData.bin` file being generated inside your VM. This should help you with first-time init (e.g. passing a Puppet config file).

Note that this isn't yet implemented in the command-line tools - you'll need to call the API directly.